# Angular typeahead debouncetime request

Tags: angular, rxjs, typeahead, debouncing

Search functionality debounce issue makes too many requests and `debounceTime` not working properly.

```html
 <search"></search>
```

```js
 search(argument: string): void {
    this.argument = argument;
      this.searchService
        .getSuggestions(this.argument )
        .pipe(debounceTime(8000), distinctUntilChanged(), take(1))
        .subscribe(
          (suggestions) => {
            this.suggestions= suggestions;
          }
        );
    }
```

Comment: You should remove take(1) from your code -  as subscription will be completed after taking first value and will create new subscription when you search second time. You can use switchMap for typeahead functionality as it will automatically cancel the previous request if new request comes.

Comment: When I replaced subscribe with switchMap the function was not executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your current implementation is not working is that you are creating a new subscription every time you enter a character.

```js
 search(argument: string): void {
    // you don't need to do this
    this.argument = argument;
    // or this
    this.live = this.argument.length >= 3;
    if (this.live) {
      this.searchService
        .getSuggestions(this.argument )
        .pipe(debounceTime(8000), distinctUntilChanged(), take(1))
        // This subscription is then called every time you enter a value
        .subscribe(
          (suggestions: Array<string>) => {
            this.suggestions= suggestions;
            this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
          }
        );
    }
```

I would use a form control for your search input like this:

```html
<input [formControl]='myControl'>`
```

In your TS, declare this as a class variable:

```js
myControl = new FormControl();
```

`FormControl` exposes `valueChanges` as an observable that you can then subscribe to.

Then you probably want to do something like this:

```js
suggestions$ = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    // use an RxJS filter here instead of using class variables like you were earlier
    filter(searchTerm => searchTerm?.length >= 3),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(8000),
    // switchMap will subscribe to the inner observable 
    // and cancel any in flight XHR requests if you create a new one
    switchMap(valueChange => 
       this.searchService.getSuggestions(valueChange)
    )
)
```

I am assuming you will have some sort of `*ngFor` to iterate through the suggestions that are returned, like so:

```html
<suggestion 
    *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions$ | async"
    [suggestion]="suggestion"
></suggestion>
```

Using the `async` pipe ensures that your subscription is tidied up on destroy of the component. You can do this in other ways (you are on the right path with your usage of `take(1)`), but a suggestion (pun unintended :D) from me would be to use the `async` pipe where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try below code for typeahead functionality

```
this.searchService
.getSuggestions((this.argument)).pipe(
    debounceTime(8000), 
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((this.argument) => {

        // Any other operation
     
    })
)
.subscribe((res) => {
    // Result
});
```

Comment: The requests are being sent every time a new input is being inserted again, even after changing it.

Comment: Hi @kukiiiku , Please check this stackoverflow, 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xqo1l2?file=src/app/app.component.ts
When you type something it displays after specified debounceTime only. Also check your imports or create a sample code in stackblitz for further investigation.